# Convergence of Expectactions

Tags: probability-theory

Show that

$X_n \xrightarrow{D} X$ iff $Ef(X_n) \rightarrow Ef(X)$ for all functions $f: R \rightarrow R$ with $|f(t)| \le 1$ for all t.

I was approaching this by using the fact that if f is bounded continuous then this holds but the bound on the first derivative does not imply any bound of f as it's domain *R* is unbounded.

Can someone please give me a hint on how to approach this problem?

(Edit)
The function f is bounded not f' as earlier.
I found a nice to way to prove this was to use the Skorokhod's representation theorem to convert $X_n \xrightarrow{D} X$ to $Y_n \xrightarrow{a.s} Y$ and then use the continuos mapping theorem.

Comment: Presumably we consider the bounded functions $f$ such that $f$ is derivable and $|f'(t)| \leqslant 1$ for each $t$. Otherwise, take $f(x)=x$ and $X_n=n^2$ with probability $1/n$ and $0$ with probability $1-1/n$. Then $X_n\to 0$ in distribution but $\mathbb E[f(X_n)]=n$. But if we do this assumption the function $f$ is continuous and bounded.

Comment: Thanks this helps. However if we assume f to be bounded then we no longer need any bound on the derivative as any existence of the derivative will imply f is continuos?

Comment: Indeed. Is it an exercise from a textbook?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's from a book. We got this as homework.

Comment: What is supposed to be equivalent to the convergence in distribution seems to imply that the sequence $(X_n)_n$ is uniformly integrable. Maybe you could try to show the equivalence under this assumption.

Comment: The assumption on the derivative makes $f$ Lipschitz continuous. But I don't see how boundedness of $f$ could be obtained, or even uniform integrability as proposed in another comment. Perhaps some things are silently assumed?

Comment: There has been a modification in the question, apparently it was a typo in the paper. I've edited the question.